# Value of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n ((\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/{k^n})-1)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

To find the value of:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n ((\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/{k^n})-1)$

The answer says: $1/2$

My attempt:

$=(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/{k^2})-1-(\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/{k^3})+1+(\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/{k^4})-1-\cdots$
$=(1+1/2^2+1/3^2+1/4^2+\cdots)-(1+1/2^3+1/3^3+1/4^3+\cdots)+(1+1/2^4+1/3^4+1/4^4+\cdots)-\cdots$
$=(1/2^2-1/2^3+1/2^4-\cdots)+(1/3^2-1/3^3+1/3^4-\cdots)+(1/4^2-1/4^3+1/4^4-...)+\cdots$
$=S_1+S_2+S_3+\cdots$

With:

$S_2=(1/2^2-1/2^3+1/2^4-\cdots)$

$S_3=(1/3^2-1/3^3+1/3^4-\cdots)$

$S_4=(1/4^2-1/4^3+1/4^4-\cdots)$

...

It looks like geometry series with alternating signs.

If I apply the geometric series value: $S=\frac{1}{1-z}$
Gives:

$S_2=2-1-1/2=1/2$

$S_3=3/2-1-1/3=1/2-1/3$

$S_4=4/3-1-1/4=1/3-1/4$

...

Original equation:

$=1/2+1/2-1/3+1/3-1/4+1/4-1/5+\cdots=1$

This is different than the answer (1/2) given.

Could any one help? Thanks,

Comment: Be careful, you can't rearrange a series if it doesn't converge absolutely.  Also, this seems to imply $\zeta(n)\to1$ as $n\to\infty$.  Is that really true?

Comment: Gregory, I think if it is a series when $n \to \infty$, then it can be freely rearranged. Am I right? As for the $ζ(n)$ it converges if $n>1$, doesn't necessarily tends to 1.

Comment: You can't rearrange a series $\sum a_n$ unless you know that $\sum|a_n|$ also converges.  And if $\zeta(n)$ does not converge to one as $n\to\infty$ than the series can't converge because $\sum a_n$ converges $\Rightarrow$ $a_n\to0$.

Comment: Also I think you've calculated $S_2$ wrong.  The sum $\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1/2)^n = \frac{1}{1-(-1/2))} - 1 + 1/2 = 1/6$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I made a calculation error on all S. Corrected and seems that after the correction, it matches the answer. I will add it as answer and see if anyone find it correct and useful.

Comment: Cool, I went ahead and upvoted your answer and posted my comment as an answer since it seems to be what got you over the hump.  Please check it off so this question can be removed from the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've calculated $S_2$ wrong. The sum $\sum_{n=2}^\infty(−1/2)^n=\frac1{1−(−1/2))}−1+1/2=1/6$

Answer (score 1):

So I made calculation error when using the equation on geometric series.

$S_2=2/3-1+1/2=1/2-1/3$ (with z=-1/2)

$S_3=3/4-1+1/3=1/3-1/4$ (with z=-1/3)

$S_4=4/5-1+1/4=1/4-1/5$ (with z=-1/4)

Sum them up gives the value of original equation:

$=1/2-1/3+1/3-1/4+1/4-1/5+...=1/2$